# Parsing values from XML using multiple namespaces .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Here is my code

```
 String MyXml = "<av:Button Name="btn_1" Width="80" Height="25" x:Uid="btn_1" av:Canvas.Left="168.1" av:Canvas.Top="95.1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">My Button Content</av:Button>";

    XmlNamespaceManager mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    mngr.AddNamespace("av", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    XmlParserContext parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, mngr, null, XmlSpace.None);

    XmlTextReader txtReader = new XmlTextReader(MyXml, XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext);

    var doc = XElement.Load(txtReader);

    var name = doc.Attribute("Name").Value;
    var width = doc.Attribute("Width").Value; 
    var Uid   = doc.Attribute("Uid").Value; // Not Working
```

I am unable to get the **Uid** because of different namespace probably, same goes for **av:Canvas.Top**.

**How to get these attributes?**

-TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate MyXml with **xmlns:av="anyNameSpaceName"** and then you can access it with,

```
  String MyXml = "<av:Button Name=\"btn_1\" Width=\"80\" Height=\"25\" x:Uid=\"btn_1\" av:Canvas.Left=\"168.1\" av:Canvas.Top=\"95.1\" xmlns:av=\"anyNameSpaceName\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">My Button Content</av:Button>";
  XNamespace ns = "anyNameSpaceName";
  var Canvat_Top= doc.Attribute(ns + "Canvas.Top").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, add all the `namespaces`

```
    XmlNamespaceManager manager= new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    mngr.AddNamespace("av", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    mngr.AddNamespace("x", "url_for_x");
```

Now, if you want to check for attributes and nodes regardless of the namespace you could simply visit each node and then loop through its attributes to find out the value.

```
    XmlNode uuidNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/namespace:node", manager);
    if (uuidNode.Attributes != nul)
      foreach(XmlAttribute oAttribute in uuidNode.Attributes)
        if (oAttribute == "UUID")
          name = oAttribute.Value;
```

As long as you add the path you want to visit in `SelectSingleNode` and your `namespaces` are declared you should be able to run through any node and get any value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        XNamespace xlink = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
        var name = doc.Attribute("Name").Value;
        var width = doc.Attribute("Width").Value;
        var Uid = doc.Attribute(xlink + "Uid").Value;
```